# Merge two data frames in r (updating and dropping values)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames:

```
data <- data.frame(ID1 = c("D1","D1","D1","D1","D2","D2"),
               ID3 = c("A","A","D","D","B","C"),
               Attribute = c("KL","KM","KL","KM","AB","AB"),
               Value = c(2,2,3,3,5,7))


data_new <- data.frame(ID1 = c("D1","D1","D2","D2"),
               ID2 = c("D1-1","D1-1","D2-1","D2-1"),
               Attribute = c("KL","TA","AB","AA"))
```

Now I would like to incorporate the `Values` and `ID3` from data in my new data frame. In addition I would like to drop some attributes and add new ones. The output should look as follows:

```
expected_output <- data.frame(ID1 = c("D1","D1","D1","D1","D2","D2","D2","D2"),
                          ID2 = c("D1-1","D1-1","D1-1","D1-1","D2-1","D2-1","D2-1","D2-1"),
                          ID3 = c("A","A","D","D","B","B","C","C"),
                          Attribute = c("KL","TA","KL","TA","AB","AA","AB","AA"),
                          Value = c(2,2,3,3,5,5,7,7))
```

Can anyone help me on this?

What I tried so far is a simple merge.

```
mergeddata <- merge(data_new,data, 
                by.x = c("ID1"),
                by.y = c("ID1"))
```

The outcome looks promising for `ID1 = D2` I would just have to drop the column `Attribute.x`". However `ID = D1` is not what I want. Rows 5-8 should not be in the new table anymore.

any help?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do.  What is the thinking from getting from data and data_new to expected_output?

Comment: Lets say ID1 would be a security in a fund (ID3) with some attributes attached to the security (ID1) and a value (position) in each fund. Now the attributes for the security changed (data_new) and they get a new ID (ID2), based on ID1. The goal is to update data with the new attributes but keeping the positions and values. Is that more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try the following:

```
mergeddata <- merge(data_new ,unique(data[, c("ID1", "ID3", "Value")]), by = "ID1")
```